# setState in React Native not causing a re-render

Tags: react-native, variables, state, rendering, conditional-operator

As can be seen in my posted code, I have a React Native class that calls a function ('getKey') in the 'componentDidMount' which is designed to retrieve some variables from storage.  This seems to be operative as expected:

```
export default class Cast extends Component {
constructor(props) {
 super(props);

 this.state = {
  admin: false,
  isPublishing: false,
  userComment: "",
  hasPermission: false,
  paused: true,
  _email: false,
  _name: false,
  _pword: false,
  _play_ID: false,
  _streamkey: false,
  _playurl: "",
  _streamurl: "",
  isLoading : true,
 };
}

getKey = async() => {
  try {
    var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('email');
    this.setState({ _email: value });
    value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('playkey');
    this.setState({ _play_ID: value });
    const playurl = "https://stream.mux.com/" + value + ".m3u8"
    this.setState({ _playurl: playurl });
    value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('castkey');
    this.setState({ _streamkey: value });
    const streamurl = "rtmp://global-live.mux.com:5222/app/" + value
    this.setState({ _streamurl: streamurl });
    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
  }
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.getKey();
}

renderCameraView = () => {
  return (
    <NodeCameraView
      style={styles.nodeCameraView}
      /* eslint-disable */
      ref={vb => {
        this.vb = vb;
      }}
      /* eslint-enable */
      outputUrl = {this.state._streamurl}
      camera={settings.camera}
      audio={settings.audio}
      video={settings.video}
      autopreview
    />
  );
};

renderPlayerView = () => {
const { paused } = this.state;
const source = {
  uri: this.state._playurl   
};
  return (
    <Video
      source={source} // Can be a URL or a local file.
//...stuff
    />
  );
};

renderEmptyView = () => {
console.log("ACTUAL _playurl value variable in renderEmptyView: " + this.state._playurl)
  const { paused } = this.state;
  const source = {
    uri: "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"
  };

  return (
    <Video
      source={source} // Can be a URL or a local file.
//...stuff
    />
  );

};

//...

render() {
  const { admin, paused, isPublishing } = this.state;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
{isLoading ? this.renderEmptyView() : !isLoading && admin ? this.renderPlayerView() : !isLoading && !admin ? this.renderCameraView() : null} 

//...stuff

    </View>
  );
```

Also near the bottom in the 'render' section I have a ternary operator which is designed to conditionally load the initial view screen based upon variable values.  When the render first occurs the 'isLoading' = true (as set in the this.state constructor) and therefore 'this.renderEmptyView()' is intended to be called to render the initial screen.

As I understand when 'setState' is used to change the value of a variable (as in my 'getKey' function)...this is supposed to cause a re-render of the environment.  However, my issue is that does not seem to happen.  I would expect that when the value of 'isLoading' is changed to 'false' (in the 'getKey' function) that should cause an environment render of either 'this.renderPlayerView()' or 'this.renderCameraView()' (based on the value of the 'admin' variable as can be seen in the code).

I know the variables in 'getKey' are being processed, the 'console.log' statement I placed in the 'renderEmptyView()' displays the following:

```
 LOG  ACTUAL _playurl value variable in renderEmptyView:
 LOG  ACTUAL _playurl value variable in renderEmptyView:
 LOG  ACTUAL _playurl value variable in renderEmptyView:
 LOG  ACTUAL _playurl value variable in renderEmptyView:
 LOG  ACTUAL _playurl value variable in renderEmptyView:
 LOG  ACTUAL _playurl value variable in renderEmptyView:
 LOG  ACTUAL _playurl value variable in renderEmptyView: https://stream.mux.com/NOk01fhhiudj9YQVGwOHFs6Ovd01Z6VGNWFJKMmEFkfOE.m3u8
```

As the log indicates, when execution is first initiated the '_playurl' variable is 'empty'...as expected (since it was initialized as 'empty' ("") in the this.state constructor) however after a number of ticks it does get changed to the value retrieved from storage.

This code technically does not throw any errors however the rendering of the environment when executed is all messed up...I just get blank/black non-functional screens and the 'this.renderPlayerView()' does not get called when the 'isLoading' variable becomes 'false'.

What am I doing wrong here?  Perhaps my understanding of the 'setState' is incorrect...or perhaps I need to use some other code syntax?  Any enlightening answers will be greatly appreciated.  I thank you in advance.

Comment: `{isLoading ? this.renderEmptyView() : admin ? this.renderPlayerView() : this.renderCameraView()}`. As far I know you must use ternary like this. If your variable admin is false, your ternary will never show Camera view.

Comment: Thanks for your response...I will give that a try when I have a chance tomorrow.  Much appreciated.

Comment: I was under the impression that ternary expressions could be chained...like If/Then/ElseIf or something very similar.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion however I am still having difficulties.  Upon execution I get a 'black screen' with no rendering at all, and an error is thrown (I believe when the '_playurl' variable is updated in the 'getKey' function)...for some reason I get an error no matter if I use "uri: this.state._playurl" or "uri: ._playurl" or "uri: {this.state._playurl}" in the 'renderPlayerView()' function.  I wondered if perhaps I could use the 'useEffect' hook (with '_playurl' as a 'dependency') to attempt to change the screen renderings...however I think it cannot be used in a class component...?

Comment: What's the error you are getting? It would be great if you share your snack or minimal snippet to reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have it straightened out...I believe the black screen I am seeing is just the latency delay...after about 15 seconds I do get my expected video stream.  I guess I had expected, even if only for a second or so...to see the initial screen rendered by 'renderEmptyView'...perhaps there is not enough time to render before the variable is changed and the 'renderPlayerView' is called.  I thank you again for your input, much appreciated.